# Can not install UBUNTU from USB or CD/drive

Tags: 12.04

I have been trying to install from flash drive, and CD with no luck . I am running a IBM ThinkCenter M50 (8189A1EU) PC Desktop with 3GB RAM.

I have gone into BIOS and changed the boot order to be CD, or REMOVABLE DEVICE first, and tried putting both of them sequentially, and then even removing HD from the list completely with no success. The machine just hangs with a black screen and a blinking cursor and allows no input.

I have also pressed F12 during normal startup and attempted to select one of these BOOT options from the menu with the same results. I even updated  the BIOS with no success. I have disabled the admin security features for all bootable devices in the BIOS.

I was reading somewhere that maybe the machine is too old to install? I also read it might have something to do with ATI card, so I disabled that in BIOS and used the on-board one. Not much happened there either. That being said i do notice that while the screen hangs while I wait for the CD or USB to boot my monitor changes resolutions from 640 x480 to 720 x 400.

All i see is blinking white underscore on black screen.

ADDENDUM -I successfully booted from the windows XP disk without problems,but no luck with the UBUNTU boot disk. As a test I even tried the UBUNTU disk on my other machine with no success. Something tells me the files extracted from the ISO and put onto the USB will not work on CD?

Comment: 3 gigs installed. There is a windows XP partition on this machine that works just fine.

Comment: Then you do have enough RAM for Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: The old Pentium 4s were 32 bit only, so are you trying to install a 32 release?  Your symptom will show trying to run a 64 bit grub on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: the installer i have is 32 bit

Comment: To do a bootable USB stick it is not sufficient to extract files from the ISO and copy them to the drive. Use Pendrive linux, or Unetbootin to create the bootable drive from the iso. Burning the ISO to a CD should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to your edits, I thought there was something wrong with your computer but now that you mention ***extracted*** and ***XP disc booting without a problem***, I'm pretty sure the problem's with your disc and flash drive.

You should burn the ISO image using proper utility tools to do it, instead of simply extracting the content onto the disc and burning it that way. There's a difference between the two, as burning it as an image will keep the bootloader whereas simply extracting won't ([for more information](https://superuser.com/a/246708)). As for the bootable USB drive, do what `To Do` mentioned instead.

The only other explanation I can give is the MD5 checksum of the ISO being wrong in the first place (possibly an incomplete download), but you should always check it after downloading it, *and* after burning it to a disc to be safe.

I'm not exactly sure of which OS you're using currently (I'm guessing XP), but here are some links which I think may help:

[CDBurnerXP, a freeware burner that should work on any Windows platform above 2000 SP4](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Intro/cdburnerxp)

[How to verify integrity for Ubuntu ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows)

Answer (score 0):

"I was reading somewhere that maybe the machine is too old to install?"

You will want to start with, not Ubuntu, but [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net), as your machine does not have the horsepower for full-on Ubuntu with Unity, a very demanding UI with requires compositing and 3D capability in your video adapter. Both of those lighter versions can be booted from a LiveUSB, and once you make up your mind which you like, you can install your preference. Until you install, the files on the hard drive are intact, and even accessible.

Comment: That cant be right. 3 gigs of ram, and INTEL Pentium 4, 2.8 GHz processor is too weak?  
ON the link below it says that "A Pentium 4, 1GHz system is the minimum recommended for a desktop system"
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/minimum-hardware-reqts.html

Comment: Also this doesnt really explain why I am unable to boot from CD or USB. I could really use some help!

Comment: I've got a p4 2.8 with 3 gigs runs 12.04 fine, I've only had "horsepower" problems with HD quality video which a new graphics card fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From within yourwindows installed,try a wubi i stallation then reboot your computer and see what you get (you can always start Windows again and remove Ubuntu installation from Add/Remove programs

WUBI guide is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

And if you have the .ISO file already, download WUBI installer from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows), where you will find installation instructions as well.

Note: WUBI installer is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and its derivatives only.

Comment: I tired installing UBUNTU form WUBI and got an error about missing files or something. I also tried to get the UBUNTU CD BOOT helper installed but got the same error.

Comment: I tried installing WUBI from the disk and got most of the way though but with an error at the end saying I was missing something. I then tried to install the CD BOOT HELPER but got the same error message. Here is the log file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/arowwny12ym4wr6/wubi-12.04.4-rev280.log

Comment: Error was EXTRACTION FAILED WITH CODE 2. What do I do now?

Comment: Download WUBI and place it inside the same folder with the iso file then run it....don't let WUBI download it.....and better redownload the iso file and verify its integrity